# Draw a probability distribution

Tags: r, statistics

The task is the following:
Use R to plot the probability function of the random variable described above. Estimate the respective probability that the sum of the three dice assumes a specific value.

I solved it like this, but I don't know if it's correct:

```
x <- function(){sum(sample(1:6, 3, replace=T))}
exp1<-replicate(10^3,x())
**hist(exp1, breaks=50, prob=T)**
```

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: Well, you have something that looks like a PDF, but is it the *correct* PDF?  We don't know, because you haven't given us the "probability function of the random variable described above".

Comment: The sum of three dice is a bump-shaped distribution with minimum value 3 and maximum value 18, with a peak around 3 times 3.5 = 10.5 ... so, on the face of it, the result you got looks plausible. I agree with the answer below that recommends `plot(table(...))` instead of `hist`.

Answer (score 2):

`hist()` is designed for continuous distributions rather than discrete ones. It sounds as though you have a discrete distribution.

The usual way to display the empirical pf for a discrete distribution is to use `plot(table(exp1)/n)`, where `n` is the number of samples. For example, with your simulation,

```r
x <- function(){sum(sample(1:6, 3, replace=T))}
exp1<-replicate(10^3,x())
plot(table(exp1)/10^3, ylab = "Probability")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you are expected to compute the theoretical pf, you'd need two vectors: `x`, the possible values, and `pf`, the probabilities for each. Then `plot(x, pf, type = "h")` will do it.